Pentaho _ Convert varchar data type to enum data type, from SQL to Postgres
I'm new to pentaho and need to convert the data type varchar in the SQL DB to a enum data type in the Postgres DB.
SELECT
  id
, tipo
, note
, stato
, nome_contatto
, channel_contatto
, createdAt
, updatedAt
, id_trigger_event
FROM dbo.Archivio_notifiche

Like the tipo column in this image; i need to make it possible to migrate the data in this column to the Postgres where the destination column is in enum data type.
This is the error message it give me.
ERROR: the column is of type enum_something but the expression is of type character varying.Suggestion: You need to rewrite or convert the type of expression

This is a rough translation.
I tried various query with CASE in the input table.
I would like to know the correct way to convert the varchar to enum across the DBs, with queries or some other methods.
